# How can I modify a oracle Linux service to run on startup from the OL Web Console?

Tags: oracle19c, oraclelinux

I am running Oracle Linux 8. From the Web Console (Cockpit Version 276.1) I see a service

```
/run/systemd/generator.late/oracledb_ORCLCDB-19c.service
```

When I start this service, the DB & listener start and things are wonderful. I would like this service to start automatically on startup.

I cannot find anyplace to click to set automatic startup. Can someone point out where to find this option?

Answer (score 1):

You can check if its enabled by executing the following command

```
systemctl is-enabled oracledb_ORCLCDB-19c
```

If it comes back as disabled you can enable it using

```
sudo systemctl enable oracledb_ORCLCDB-19c
```

PS: would work if you had terminal access, haven't tried the web cockpit.

Comment: Sometimes I wonder how Oracle maintains any market share. Their products are fairly bullet prof, but the simplest things require jumping through too many hoops.

Comment: sudo systemctl enable oracledb_ORCLCDB-19c works fine. If you are trying to make a tool for services, why wouldn't you include this functionality in the tool? SMH